# Blender 2.8 - Can't select hair in point select mode in particle edit

Tags: particles, hair

I've recently begun learning how to work with particle hair in Blender, and in some videos about it I've seen that you can select individual hair keys and have the hair tools only affect the selected keys.

I've found the selection modes in particle edit mode, however the "Point" selection mode does not appear to be working. I can't select anything, using A and Alt+A to select and deselect all do nothing. Tip select mode appears to work, but it only allows me to use the tools on the tip of the hair key which is not what I want.

Is there something I am missing or is this a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: I've had this problem in the past, but for me it's fixed in 2.8. I think you might have a bug on your hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to look at this some more and it's only an issue in the blend file I was working with. The point select mode works as expected in brand new files.

I originally created the file in 2.79, perhaps that's part of the cause?

I can append everything from the old file into a new file and everything works, so I am going to go with that as my solution. But I'll keep the old files around and maybe file a bug report.